# Send from laravel a data type blob to Oracle db

Tags: laravel, oracle, plsql, blob

I'm having a problem executing this PL SQL procedure. The problem is that the :p6 argument has to be a blob file for the oracle database and what I have in Laravel is a file, string type in base64. How is it possible to pass a blob file to it? that is, that blob_file is not a string in base64

```
public function insertFile (string $table_name, string $file_type, string $file_type_extension, string $file_name, string $file_path)
{

    $multimedia_id=-1;

    $table="CIUD_".$table_name."_DOC";

    $blob_file = (self::getDocumentFromFront($file_path) );
    
    $res = DB::statement("BEGIN MMD_UTIL.INSERT_FILE(:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7); END;", [
        'CIU',
        $table,
        $file_type,
        $file_type_extension,
        $file_name,
        $blob_file,
        &$multimedia_id // Passing the output parameter by reference
    ]);

    dd($multimedia_id);
    return $multimedia_id;

}
```

For example, if I do gettype($blob_file) I get that it is a string type and I think that is causing me problems.

by the way getDocumentFromFront is:

```
function getDocumentFromFront(string $filepath){
    
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {

        $content = file_get_contents($filepath);


        $blob = base64_encode($content);

        return $blob;
    }
    else{
        return "bad data";
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://phpcoder.tech/convert-string-to-blob-and-blob-to-string-in-php/